# angularJS: Dynamic header sorting not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I am trying to implement a solution to sort a table by clicking its headers, using AngularJS.

I found a good example after doing a Google search: https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular

I am able to see the up and down arrows, but the table does not sort when I click them.

I think the problem resides in how the JSON object is formatted in my situation. I have not been able to figure it out, and I am hoping that with the information that I am providing on this post, I can get some help to understand what I am doing incorrectly.

Here is a copy of the JavaScript:

```
    (function (define, angular) {
    'use strict';
    define(function () {

        var opportunityController = function ($scope, Metadata, Factory) {

            var vm = this;

            //set the default sort type
            vm.sortType = 'Products';            

            //set the default sort order
            vm.sortReverse = false;             

            Factory.Data(caller.sp, caller.filter).then(function (payload) {
                var data = angular.fromJson(payload.data).Table;
                ProcessData(data);
            });

            function ProcessData(data) {
                if (angular.isDefined(data)) {
                    var counter = 0;
                    vm.products = [];
                    vm.productsSet = FindByAsObjectArray(function (x) {
                        return (x.TypeName == "Product");
                    }, data);

                    for (var index = 0, length = vm.productsSet.length; index < length; index++) {
                        vm.products[index] = {
                            data: vm.productsSet[index]
                        };                                                
                    }
                }                    
            }
        };
        return ['$scope','Metadata','Factory',opportunityController];
    });
})(define, angular);
```

I got it to work, final version: https://jsfiddle.net/itortu/nhhppf53/

Many thanks.

Comment: So you're doing a number of things not quite right here.  I would suggest checking out the orderBy functionality here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy .   If you want to stick with the way you are trying to do it you'll need to put a $watch on your sortType and sortReverse values and do the sorting when the value changes, but I think you'll find the orderBy much easier to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Scott. I am doing a few things incorrectly for sure, this is my first attempt at doing something like this. Can I ask one thing, do you thing that among the things I am doing wrong, the format of the array of objects is one of them?

Comment: The JSON should be fine. It just looks like some flat objects with properties. For display and sorting that will work.

Comment: Why not use something like [ngTable](http://ng-table.com)?

Comment: @Scott, I was able to follow the example in the angularJS docs. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using controllerAs

```
ng-controller="Company:OpportunityController as opportunity"
```

therefor you have to reference sortType and sortReverse in your ng-click like so:

```
ng-click="opportunity.sortType = 'Products'; opportunity.sortReverse = !opportunity.sortReverse"
```

Comment: Thank you Guenter, I have updated my html, I added the reference to opportunity in the mark-up, and also changed the $scope to vm. Still does not work.

Comment: could you please provide a plunker with your example.

Comment: I would bu t I don't know how to make it work outside of the framework in which I am working currently.

Comment: I prepared one for you, this is not exactly your code but similar, maybe it helps to figure out your problem. See here http://plnkr.co/edit/OYKuoUHt960lOvrA6yqq?p=preview

Comment: I was able to add a fiddle, it works but only the fiddle, when I move the code to my real solution, the code does not work. Probably because ng-app. https://jsfiddle.net/itortu/nhhppf53/

Comment: I got it to work. I needed to replace null values with "". Does anybody know of a way to work this around? Many thanks